# My fullscreen div wont seem to work

Tags: html, css, height

Just a quick one. I was working on my site and must have broken something because the first div should be fullscreen:

http://jsfiddle.net/c24RN/1/

```
<div class="container1">
    <a href="#cont1">
        <img src="img/down.png"></img>
    </a>
    <h1><?php echo $lines[1]; ?></h1>
    <a href="<?php echo $lines[2]; ?>"><h3><?php echo $lines[0]; ?></h3></a>
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="pauseMusic()">Pause/Play</button>
    <div class="canvasdiv">
        <audio id="music" src="<?php echo $files[$file] ?>" preload="auto"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is the main Div code

Any reason why it wont work?

(Ignore the php)

Not a dupe post btw, different issue

Comment: you don't have a stylesheet class _canvasdiv_. Might this be the problem?

Comment: Removing doesnt seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have positioned your div absolute which is causing this issue. Remove it and also remove the padding and margins to the html and body tags (as suggested by the 404 error)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vabhdman/UpGA8/)

```
.container1 {
height: 100%;
}

/* no position absolute */
html, body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the default margin / padding from the document:

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c24RN/2/)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have misunderstood, the problem was that there is a div before that, that should also be fullscreen.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand what you mean. There is a div before what? Can you set up an example that clearly shows the issue?

Comment: Ill try to explain. I Have 2 divs, They are both fullscreen divs and the buttons at the top corner of the page scroll between them. The prolem is that the first div seems to have no height. If the second is removed the first can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

should solve the problem.